# correlative HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code where to order a table with a correlative, but I want if this state is completed it does not respect the correlative
example: if I remove the correlative `1` it does not sort the correlative, and if I remove the last row in this case corretive `2` and I add a new row this correlative would be 3.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  orden_correlative();

  /*Delelete row*/
  $('#tbl_cotizacion').on('click', 'button.remove', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    orden_correlative();
  });
  /*New row*/
  $("#btn_save_line").click(function() {

    var newRow = document.getElementById('tbl_cotizacion').insertRow();
    newRow.innerHTML = "<tr><td align='center'> </td><td>2</td><button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm remove'> x </button> </td></tr>";
    orden_correlative();
  });

});

function orden_correlative() {
  var i = 1;
  var complete_order = $('#complete_order').val();
  $("#tbl_cotizacion tbody > tr").each(function() {
    var cell = $(this).find('td');
    $(cell[0]).text(i);
    i++;
  });
  $("input[name=max_line]").val(i - 1);
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_save_line">Add</button>

<select class="custom-select custom-select-sm" id="complete_order">
  <option selected>Complete order ?</option>
  <option value="N">N</option>
  <option value="Y">Y</option>
</select>
<hr>
<table id="tbl_cotizacion" class="table table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr class="table-warning">
      <th width="5%" align='center'>correlative</th>
      <th width="5%">qyt</th>
      <th width="5%"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align='center'> </td>
      <td> 4 </td>
      <td><button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm remove'> x </button> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align='center'> </td>
      <td> 5 </td>
      <td><button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm remove'> x </button> </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="text" name="max_line" id="max_line" value="">
```

Comment: Correlative works fine.i don't understand the problem.

Comment: If the order is complete this would not be respect the correlative start from the last correlative line